Google Cloud Deploy `images` parameter seems to have no effect
I have the following deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:            
      containers:
        - name: nginx-base
          image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/registry/nginx/base:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always

and am using the following cloud deploy command to deploy it:
gcloud deploy releases create "my-deployment-001" \
    --delivery-pipeline my-pipeline \
    --project my-project \
    --region us-central1 \
    --annotations "$annotations" \
    --skaffold-file "path/to/skaffold.yaml" \
    --images "nginx-base=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/registry/nginx/base:<IMAGE TAG>"

It seems that the nginx-base image is not being given the correct tag. Here's part of of the rendered manifests:
        - image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/registry/nginx/base:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always

which still contains the old tag. I've tried setting the images flag to something like old-url:latest=new-url:tag, but that doesn't seem to work either. the documentation seems to imply that one of these would work.
What am I doing wrong?

I'm unfamiliar with Skaffold but your "skaffold" is a Kubernetes Deployment not a Skaffold

@DazWilkin Thanks! sorry, you're right. I actually wanted to paste the deployment but accidently called it the skaffold. Editing

You piqued my interest and so I had a go with Cloud Deploy (using Cloud Run). It works for me. In my Cloud Run service YAML, I used an arbitrary image value of foo. I was then able to gcloud deploy releases create release-001 --delivery-pipeline=test --images=foo=${GAR}/${PROJECT}/${REG}/${IMG}:blue and confirm that a Cloud Run service was deployed using image tag blue. I then gcloud deploy releases create release-002 --delivery-pipeline=test --images=foo=${GAR}/${PROJECT}/${REG}/${IMG}:green and a new Cloud Run service revision was created using green.

What I find confusing is that I didn't directly reference skaffold.yaml in either deploy apply or deploy releases create and so I'm assuming it's found by default.

@DazWilkin when you view the rendered manifest in cloud deploy, does it have the old tag or the new tag? Thanks for entertaining this. fwiw I'll accept an answer like "works for me" as correct, since this is user error on my part.

I'll copy what I did into an Answers and will add details of the manifest per your comment.

Environment:
PROJECT=...
REGION=...
REG="..."

# Artifact Registry
GAR="${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REG}"

# Container Registry: Kuard
# My go-to test container ;-)
GCR="gcr.io/kuar-demo"

IMG="kuard-amd64"
TAG="blue"

Cloud IAM
NUMBER=$(\
  gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(projectNumber)")

EMAIL="${NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role="roles/clouddeploy.jobRunner"

# This one is weird!?
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${EMAIL} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser" \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role="roles/run.developer"

Artifact Registry
Replace podman with your tool:
podman pull ${GCR}/${IMG}:${TAG}

podman tag \
  ${GCR}/${IMG}:${TAG} \
  ${GAR}/${IMG}:${TAG}

gcloud auth print-access-token \
| podman login \
  ${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev \
  --username=oauth2accesstoken \
  --password-stdin

podman push ${GAR}/${IMG}:${TAG}

Cloud Deploy
clouddeploy.yaml:
apiVersion: deploy.cloud.google.com/v1
kind: DeliveryPipeline
metadata:
  name: kuard
description: kuard pipeline
serialPipeline:
  stages:
  - targetId: kuard   # References the Target metadata.name below
    profiles: [kuard] # References a skaffold.yaml profiles[].name 
---
apiVersion: deploy.cloud.google.com/v1
kind: Target
metadata:
  name: kuard
description: Cloud Run development service
run:
  location: projects/[REDACTED]/locations/[REDACTED]

kuard.yaml:
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kuard
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: foo # Replaced 

Then:
gcloud deploy apply \
--file=clouddeploy.yaml \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

RELEASE="release-001"
gcloud deploy releases create ${RELEASE} \
--delivery-pipeline=kuard \
--images=foo=${GAR}/${IMG}:${TAG} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

Test
Deployed the Cloud Run service successfully
gcloud run services describe kuard \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(spec.template.spec.containers[0].image)"

[REDACTED]/kuard-amd64:blue


NOTE 'blue'

Apply a different tag:
podman tag \
  ${GAR}/${IMG}:blue \
  ${GAR}/${IMG}:green

podman push ${GAR}/${IMG}:green

Deploy a new release
RELEASE="release-002"
gcloud deploy releases create ${RELEASE} \
--delivery-pipeline=kuard \
--images=foo=${GAR}/${IMG}:green \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud run services describe kuard \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(spec.template.spec.containers[0].image)"

[REDACTED]/kuard-amd64:green


NOTE now green

Tidy
# NOTE --quiet
gcloud run services delete kuard \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--quiet

# NOTE --force (delete children: releases?)
gcloud deploy delete \
--file=clouddeploy.yaml \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--force

gcloud artifacts docker images delete \
${REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REG}/kuard-amd64 \
--delete-tags \
--quiet

